How do I find the rows with some columns having the same values but another column having different values?
In a dataframe, I want to locate the rows with col1, col2, and col3 having the same values but col4 having different values.
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'col0': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    'col1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'col2': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'col3': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1],
    'col4': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.sort_values(by='col4')
df['same_col1_col2'] = df.duplicated(subset=['col1', 'col2'], keep=False)
df['different_col3'] = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].transform('nunique') > 1
df['final_flag'] = df['same_col1_col2'] & df['different_col3']
df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for symbol in df['col0'].unique():
    df_symbol = df[df['col0'] == symbol]
    df_filtered = df_symbol[df_symbol['final_flag']].drop_duplicates(subset=['col1', 'col2'], keep='first')
    df_result = pd.concat([df_result, df_filtered])
df_result = df_result.drop(columns=['same_col1_col2', 'different_col3', 'final_flag']).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_result)

Is there a better way to do it?

df[(df["col1"] == df["col2"]) & (df["col2"] == df["col3"]) & (df["col4"] != df["col3"])]?

Use boolean indexing with eq+all and ne:
# are col1/col2/col3 identical?
m1 = df[['col2', 'col3']].eq(df['col1'], axis=0).all(axis=1)

# is col4 different?
m2 = df['col1'].ne(df['col4'])

# if both conditions are true, keep the row
out = df.loc[m1&m2]

Output:
  col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
0    A     1     1     1    10
4    B     2     2     2    50

Intermediates:
  col0  col1  col2  col3  col4     m1    m2  m1&m2
0    A     1     1     1    10   True  True   True
1    A     1     1     2    20  False  True  False
2    A     1     1     3    30  False  True  False
3    B     2     2     1    40  False  True  False
4    B     2     2     2    50   True  True   True
5    C     3     3     1    60  False  True  False


Here is a way using nunique() to determine if all the columns in the list same_cols are the same. If nunique returns a 1, that means there is only 1 unique value in the list, or that all the values are the same.
same_cols = ['col1','col2','col3']
diff_col = 'col4'
df[same_cols].nunique(axis=1) & df[same_cols].ne(df[diff_col],axis=0).all(axis=1)

Output:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False


import pandas as pd

data = {
    'col0': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    'col1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'col2': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'col3': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1],
    'col4': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

exp = '(col1 == col2) & (col1 == col3) & (col1 != col4)'

res = df.query(exp)
print(res)

'''
  col0  col1  col2  col3  col4
0    A     1     1     1    10
4    B     2     2     2    50
'''

